# How to fix Active MQ Wildfly warning - Page file 000002707.page had incomplete records at position 373,401 at record number 9?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

How to fix following Wildfly Warnings:

```
2019-10-09 15:15:04,179 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$2@216f6b3e-1182524264)) AMQ222033: Page file 000002707.page had incomplete records at position 373,401 at record number 9
2019-10-09 15:15:05,182 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-remoting-threads-ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=3bea749a-88f7-11e7-b497-27b2839ef45c-1594512315-717665458)) AMQ222033: Page file 000002707.page had incomplete records at position 373,401 at record number 9
2019-10-09 15:15:05,185 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-11 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$2@216f6b3e-1182524264)) AMQ222033: Page file 000002707.page had incomplete records at position 373,401 at record number 9
```

I only get one link on google which suggests server crashes but i am not sure how to stop this -> https://developer.jboss.org/thread/154232

It contains Apache Camel Project which picks 20,000 messages put on queue and many of them discards and other processed not sure if that are related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked forum post does a fine job of explaining the likely reason why page file was corrupted. To "fix" the problem I recommend you consume all the messages you can from the affected queue, stop the broker, and remove the corrupted page file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
In Wildfly Server i can find a folder with name (e8d94825-d922-11e9-b3a8-df022380ea02)  in path -> "wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/servers/servergroup-name/data/activemq/paging". Inside that big name folder i can find few files (000002820.page ; 000002707.page.invalidPage etc.). Shall i remove all Page FIles? These are from single date only. It is production so not sure what will happen if i remove all

Comment: It worked. I have found path and removed for time being.